# Как обновить/перезаписать объект в массиве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть массив:

```
var list = [{
    status:0,
    id:1,
    img:"/assets/images/user-avatar-cropped.png",
    value:110,
    result:1
},{
    status:0,
    id:2,
    img:"/assets/images/user-avatar-cropped.png",
    value:120,
    result:1
},
{
    status:0,
    id:3,
    img:"/assets/images/user-avatar-cropped.png",
    value:130,
    result:1
},
{
    status:0,
    id:4,
    img:"/assets/images/user-avatar-cropped.png",
    value:140,
    result:1
},]
```

Массив нужно обновлять, например. Нужно изменить объект в котором значение id = 1, и задать ему status = 2, а result = 0.

Логику примерно понимаю что сначала нужно этот объект из массива удалить, а потом заново запушить с новыми(нужными) значениями.

1. Как удалить объект из массива с соответствующим id (например удалить объект там где id = 1)?
2. Можно ли как-то просто обновить объект (без его удаления и последующего добавления).
   Ну или есть ли вообще другие решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через цикл перебрать массив, найти в нем элемент с нужным id и заменить статус, можно

```
changeDesc = (id, status, result) => {
    let item = list.find(x => x.id === id);
    item.status = status;
    item.result = result;
    };

changeDesc( 1, 2, 0);
console.log(list);
```

В данном случае не происходит удаления элемента, как вы предполагали, а он изменяет свое значение.

Для удаления элемента из массива можно использовать конструкцию `array.splice(index, 1);`:

```
function removeElement( id) {
       for (let i in list) {
         if (list[i].id == id) {
            list.splice(i, 1);
            break;
         }
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Удалять ничего не нужно. Достаточно обратиться к полю и заменить:

```
list[0].id = 666;
list[0].status = 1;
```

А вот как ты будешь искать поле - вопрос другой. Например в цикле бежать по массиву и искать объект с нужным id или как-то еще

```
list.forEach(function (element) {
  if (element.id == 1) {
    element.id = 666;
    element.status = 1;
  }    
});
```

Comment: как раз таки и нужен пример как найти объект с нужным мне id

Comment: @kiLLro не вижу этого в вопросе. написано `Как удалить объект из массива с соответствующим id?` и  `Можно ли как-то просто обновить объект (без его удаления и последующего добавления).`...... но добавил пример

Answer (score 1):

Находите объект при помощи метода `find()`:

```
var found = list.find((obj) => {
    return obj.id === 1;
});
```

Изменяйте необходимые свойства простым переопределением:

```
found.status = 2; found.result = 0;
```

Но в идеале сначала стоит проверить, найден ли элемент:

```
if (found) {
    found.status = 2; found.result = 0;
}
```

Если может быть найдено несколько элементов по одному `id`, то воспользуйтесь методом `filter()`:

```
var foundArr = list.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.id === 1;
});
```

И изменяйте значение циклически:

```
foundArr.forEach((found) => {
    found.status = 2;
    found.result = 0;
});
```